# SICK-LMS200 on Ros Electric

Tags: ros, sicklms, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Way back when I used player, I had to do a delay to give the laser time to start scanning. Assuming I had to do this again, I found this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12753/problem-using-sick-lms200-laser-with-sicktoolbox/); however, the answer appears to not work in electric. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

The reason  this answer is not applicable is due to the lack of a

```
/ros/electric/stacks/sicktoolbox/build/sicktoolbox-1.0/c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMS.cc
```

directory. Any help?

Thanks,

-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38472/sick-lms200-on-ros-electric/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that is still necessary? According to [ticket/4138](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4138) for `laser_drivers` an initial delay should now be supported by the standard package (added in [changeset/38987](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/changeset/38987)).

---

EDIT: apparently those changes are only in the Fuerte version of the toolbox (thanks @Chad Rockey). For Electric, you could do a checkout of the package and apply the specific patches yourself, backporting them. Be sure to checkout the appropriate version of the sources.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-10**:
How do I configure the delay?

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-10**:
Looks like it is [just a parameter](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/laser_drivers/trunk/sicktoolbox_wrapper/ros/sicklms/sicklms.cpp?rev=38987#L175), so add it to the list of parameters of the node in your launch file?

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2012-07-10**:
The parameter for the pioneers and the sick toolbox has only been released for Fuerte.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-10**:
We cannot use fuerte because the p2os driver doesn't exist for fuerte yet. Due to that limitation, how should we proceed?